# Makefile... creating a static library

Tags: c, makefile

please can somebody help me with this makefile... What is wrong with this ?

```
NAME = libft.a
SRCS = ft_memccpy.c ft_putnbr.c ft_strequ.c ft_strnequ.c \
       ft_memchr.c      ft_putnbr_fd.c  ft_striter.c    ft_strnew.c \
       ft_memcmp.c      ft_putstr.c     ft_striteri.c   ft_strnstr.c \
       ft_atoi.c        ft_memcpy.c     ft_putstr_fd.c  ft_strjoin.c    ft_strrchr.c\
       ft_bzero.c       ft_memdel.c     ft_strcat.c     ft_strlcat.c    ft_strstr.c \
       ft_isalnum.c ft_memmove.c    ft_strchr.c     ft_strlen.c     ft_strsub.c \
       ft_isalpha.c ft_memset.c     ft_strclr.c     ft_strmap.c     ft_strtrim.c \
       ft_isascii.c ft_putchar.c    ft_strcmp.c     ft_strmapi.c    ft_tolower.c \
       ft_isdigit.c ft_putchar_fd.c ft_strcpy.c     ft_strncat.c    ft_toupper.c \
       ft_isprint.c ft_putendl.c    ft_strdel.c     ft_strncmp.c \
       ft_memalloc.c   ft_putendl_fd.c ft_strdup.c     ft_strncpy.c \
OBJ = $(SRCS:.c=.o)
all: $(NAME)
$(NAME):
    gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror $(SRCS)
    ar rc $(NAME) $(OBJ)
    ranlib $(NAME)
clean:
    bin/rm -f *.o
fclean: clean
    bin/rm -f libft.a
re: fclean all
```

I still get this error : Makefile:14: *** Recursive variable `SRCS' references itself (eventually).  Stop.
How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have a stray line continuation escape at the end of the values being assigned to your `SRCS` variable.

make sees this line at then end

```
       ft_memalloc.c   ft_putendl_fd.c ft_strdup.c     ft_strncpy.c \
```

and thinks it needs to include the next line in the value of `SRCS` too.

Only the next line is `OBJ = $(SRCS:.c=.o)` which references `$(SRCS)` and creates the loop that make is complaining about.

Either remove that stray backslash or add a blank line between those two lines.